# Bootstrap fix text line

Tags: bootstrap

```
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Name</a>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler order-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar7">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <form class="my-auto w-100 d-inline-block">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0" placeholder="Найти...">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar7">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Мои покупки</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Меню</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Каталог</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить, чтоб не переносило пробел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте text-nowrap класс

```
<a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Мои покупки</a>
```